# Detect Transparent Image Collisions on paper.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

Right now I'm trying to make a game where a ball bounces off of some transparent images in paper.js. What happens is the ball is on the image but on the transparent part, therefore saying that it intersects. Right now I'm using

```
circle.intersects(raster)
```

Is it possible in paper.js to detect when the ball touches the not-transparent part of the image?

Comment: No, the Boolean Operations part of the code only works with Paths. You could theoretically write code that auto-traces the "edges" of non-transparent paths of Rasters and create Paths but I think that's an overkill. Use Paths.

Comment: Ok. Can I export the svg and then import it again? Or would it still be an image?

Comment: It would still be an Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#getaveragecolor-object, you can check the not-transparent intersection by

```
var color = raster.getAverageColor(circle);
var nonTransperentIntersection = color && (color.alpha !== 0);
```

Comment: This gives a yes/no result: "yes, ball intersects non-transparent color". Can I also get the position of the intersection?